# Merge two rows in pandas if None or nan

Tags: python, pandas, nan, pandas-groupby

For a given data frame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 2], 
    'name': ['Peter', 'Max', None], 
    'age': [50.0, np.nan, 60.0]
})
```

I want to `groupby` and combine the data if there is just a `None` or `nan` in the column of the grouped row, so that the resulting df should look like

```
        age     id  name
id              
1   0   50.0    1   Peter
2   1   60.0    2   Max
```

Is there a neat solution better than this mine:

```
def f(df):
    names = set(df['name']) - {None}
    if len(names) == 1:
        df['name'] = names.pop()
    else:
        print('Error: Names are not mergeable:', names)

    ages = {age for age in df['age'] if ~np.isnan(age)}
    if len(ages) == 1:
        df['age'] = ages.pop()
    else:
        print('Error: Ages are not mergeable:', ages)

    df = df.drop_duplicates()
    return df

df.groupby('id').apply(f)
```

Comment: What if you have more than two rows that have missing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably be the slowest solution, you can sort the nan to last and drop them inside groupby i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 2,1,2], 
    'name': ['Peter', 'Max', None,'Daniel','Sign'], 
    'age': [50.0, np.nan, 60.0,40,30]
})
#    age  id    name
#0  50.0   1   Peter
#1   NaN   2     Max  
#2  60.0   2    None
#3  40.0   1  Daniel
#4  30.0   2    Sign

df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.apply(sorted,key=pd.isnull).dropna()).reset_index(drop=True)

    age  id    name
0  50.0   1   Peter
1  40.0   1  Daniel
2  60.0   2     Max
3  30.0   2    Sign
```

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` + `first`

```
df.groupby('id').first()
Out[877]: 
     age   name
id             
1   50.0  Peter
2   60.0    Max
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it does not answer my question, I think. It assumes that there is no conflict, right? Assume we have another row with `[1, 'Daniel', 40.0]` and it does also not work, if the group starts with a  `None`.